# Find and Move Text in OpenOffice Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer

Is it possible to search for a specific text in cells and move it?

For example: "ABCD [45] - City"

Result: "[45] ABCD - City"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

It is possible by code, formulae or search/replace (using regex).

In your example you search for something in square brackets and put this finding in front.

A regular expression search here will be

**search for:** `(.*)(\[.*\] )(.*)`
**replace by:** `$2$1$3`

Don't forget to tick the option "regular expression" 
[Everything to search and replace with this is explained in online help: F1]

If you want code or formulae to have the task accomplished: ask more specific!